# как циклом for рассмотреть каждый элемент многомерного массива

Tags: python, numpy

например, есть массив

```
list = np.array([['p', 'r', 'h', 'j', 'p'],
    ['g', 'y', 'k', 'l', 'e'],
    ['p', 't', 'p', 't', 'x']])
```

я делаю shape и добавляю счетчик

```
x, y = list.shape
counter = 0
```

потом пытаюсь перебрать элементы массива

```
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        if j == 'p':
            counter += list[j]
print(counter)
```

но в итоге получается 0.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

Comment: что-то начало не отображается: например, есть массив 

```list = np.array([['p', 'r', 'h', 'j', 'p'],
    ['g', 'y', 'k', 'l', 'e'],
    ['p', 't', 'p', 't', 'x']])```

Comment: Проверять нужно `if list[i,j] == 'p'`, а не `j == 'p'`.

Comment: ооо, спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 3):

При работе с `numpy` вообще не нужно использовать циклы, операции обычно делаются сразу над всем массивом. Например, если я правильно понял, что вы хотите посчитать, это делается гораздо проще:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([['p', 'r', 'h', 'j', 'p'],
    ['g', 'y', 'k', 'l', 'e'],
    ['p', 't', 'p', 't', 'x']])

print((arr == 'p').sum())
# 4
```

То есть просто сравниваете сразу весь массив с нужным значением, потом суммируете, пользуясь тем, что `True` считается как `1`, а `False` как `0`.

И не нужно называть ваши переменные ключевыми словами питона, `list` - это тип в питоне, вы его скрываете, называя переменную этим именем, потом сюрприз будет, когда вы захотите воспользоваться типом `list`.

Но если всё же захотите через циклы, то и это лучше делать более "питонячим" способом - перебором сущностей, а не индексов (если вы просто анализируете сущности и вам не нужно их менять):

```py
counter = 0
for row in arr:
    for item in row:
        if item == 'p':
            counter += 1
print(counter)
# 4
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень четко, подробно и понятно!